# Sorting Xcode project file in Xcode 10, to clean the project file changes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10

How can we sort the changes in Xcode project file? For example, If we clone then add or delete any files from the project Xcode project file will change in the many places. Is there any way to sort the file with the changes.

I have seen some **rake tidy** command to sort. Using some **Python** and **Perl** scripts.

Todo: I would like to clean the project file and sort with the changes.

Does anyone have the idea about this? 
If you see the image there are may change showing in the project file. But I have added only one file to the project.

Steps:  Clone any IOS project from github.com -> Add file to project,
Then goto source control. -> click on Commit. See the changes. 
It is showing many changes. I would like to rearrange as previous and modifications want to see in one place.

[image: Xcode Project file changes.]

Comment: What do you meant by **sort the file with the changes.**

Comment: The project file is (more or less) simple xml; you could create an xslt transform to re-sort it (alphabetically?).

Comment: I think it's actually in (Old-Style) plist format.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the screenshot below when you select Project navigator tab on the left Xcode have 2 buttons to sort files, the first from the left shows only recent files and the second shows files with source controls change.

[image: Xcode sort buttons]

Comment: I have added image regarding the issue.